# Dynamically insert angular component as a child of another component

Tags: angular, components

I've seen a few examples of how to do this here and around the 'net, but when I try it, my child component is inserted into the DOM as a peer of the target component. 
Here is markup I'm working with:

```
<div #target></div>
<button (click)="AddTile()">Add Tile</button>
```

Here is the parent component code:

```
import { Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild }     from '@angular/core';
import { TileComponent } from './tile/tile.component';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

 export class AppComponent{
  title = 'app works!';

  @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  AddTile() {
    const factory =   this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TileComponent);
    const res = this.target.createComponent(factory);
  }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
<div #target></div>
<tile-component></tile-component>
<tile-component></tile-component>
```

The expected output is:

```
<div #target>
  <tile-component></tile-component>
  <tile-component></tile-component>
</div>
```

Comment: are you planning to use different dynamic components based on user action?

Comment: No, the same component. It won't be based on user action either, but I'll need to dynamically add a varying number of those components at runtime. I'm using a button here as part of a POC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `ng-container` as your target, which leaves no element in the DOM. So you'll be left with just the component inside your `div`:

```
<div>
    <ng-container #target></ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work. I had tried using a div, which does yield the same result, except, of course that the div remains in the DOM, which although not a show stopper, it is still undesirable. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I am wondering now, since the component is always the same, can't you just add `ngFor`  in your template which loops over a dummy array whose length is the number of components you need?

Comment: That is an option as well. I'm investigating the various ways to do this. Looping might actually be easiest.